# Using python to find image template in bigger image regardless of scale

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scale

I have a gray-scale image and a gray-scale template (a smaller image) which are represented by numpy arrays (values 1-255). I know that the template exists as part of the bigger image, and I want to find its size and location (e.g. x,y value for top left corner) in the bigger image.

It would be simple if the images were the same scale, since I could, for each possible position subtract the template from the bigger image and see where the absolute value of the result was lowest.

However, since the scale can vary, this would not work. Is there a simple method to do this, preferably one I could program myself?

Comment: Could you please add a couple of examples?